# Parsing issue in WCF rest service

Tags: c#, wcf, multipartform-data

I am getting **content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1** 
in the parsed value for multipart data
when parsing the data

I have used below parser class
[https://bitbucket.org/lorenzopolidori/http-form-parser/src/a48defaac3b2c8a4b89152bffb8a2eb33ad57e53/HttpMultipartParser.cs?at=default](http://HttpMultiPartParser)

I have a key named user_id with value "3"
but when parsing I am seeing additional data (headers ) along with value "3"

Response is like this

content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

3

Comment: What is the question here ? What do you expect in the response ?